# Описание класса, принимающего явные аргументы

Tags: python

Есть код, который генерирует пароль по заданной длине

```
class PasswordGenerator:
    def Generate(password_length):
        password = ''
        for i in range (int(password_length)):
            rand_matrix_row = random.randint(0, 3)
            password = password + matrix[rand_matrix_row][random.randint(0, len(matrix[rand_matrix_row]))-1]
        return(password)
```

Как можно сделать так, чтобы при вызове `Generate` функция принимала только явные значения типа `int`?

То есть, например, когда я вызываю `random.randint()`, интерпретатор мне сообщает, какие значения принимает `randint()` и их тип: `(a: int, b: int) -> int`

Сейчас интерпретатор при вызове сообщает мне следующее:
`(password_length: PasswordGenerator) -> str`

Answer (score 0):

> Как можно сделать так, чтобы при вызове `Generate` функция принимала
> только явные значения типа `int`?
>
> То есть, например, когда я вызываю `random.randint()`, интерпретатор
> мне сообщает, какие значения принимает `randint()` и их тип: `(a: int, b: int) -> int`
>
> Сейчас интерпретатор при вызове сообщает мне следующее:
> `(password_length: PasswordGenerator) -> str`

Интерпретатор сам никак типы не показывает (и не проверяет), скорее всего это IDE выводит типы метода и отображает их.

`(password_length: PasswordGenerator)` показывает из-за того, что у обычных методов первым аргументом должен идти `self`, через который в метод передается сам объект при вызове метода от объекта, соответсвенно у первого аргумента тип - такой же как сам класс, в котором находится метод. Чтобы тип аргумента определялся правильно, нужно объявить метод статическим (добавив декоратор `@staticmethod`):

```
class PasswordGenerator:
    @staticmethod
    def Generate(password_length):
        password = ''
        for i in range (int(password_length)):
            rand_matrix_row = random.randint(0, 3)
            password = password + matrix[rand_matrix_row][random.randint(0, len(matrix[rand_matrix_row]))-1]
        return(password)
```

Статический метод - это метод, который вообще никак не зависит от состояния объекта или класса, по сути - просто отдельная функция, которую решили поместить внутрь класса. В данном случае у вас именно такой метод. Но если бы, например, переменная `matrix` была не глобальной, а полем объекта, то пришлось бы ваш метод сделать обычным, добавить параметр `self`, и обращаться к `matrix` через `self.matrix`.

Чтобы явно указать типы аргументов и возвращаемого значения функции, нужно использовать аннотации:

```
class PasswordGenerator:
    @staticmethod
    def Generate(password_length: int) -> str:
        password = ''
        for i in range (int(password_length)):
            rand_matrix_row = random.randint(0, 3)
            password = password + matrix[rand_matrix_row][random.randint(0, len(matrix[rand_matrix_row]))-1]
        return(password)
```

В любом случае, выведенный автоматически или указанный через аннотации тип никак сам по себе интерпретатором при работе программы не проверяется. Он может проверяться внешними инструментами, например IDE или линтерами, такими как mypy.